# How should we manage platform dependencies in DXA?

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

We're trying to get DXA working on Websphere (both WAS and Liberty). We're trying to minimise the conflicts between jars that are present in the framework and in the application server. We can see that the framework pulls in jars from tomcat, jboss, and perhaps other things that are not relevant to a successful Websphere installation.

We're currently looking at editing the POM to exclude these dependencies. Is there a cleaner/better way to manage this within DXA 1.7?

Is there a good way to know whether a given dependency is only present to support a given platform?

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and elaborate which jars are according to you only for tomcat and jboss? I've mentioned in another answer that Websphere is different in the sense that it comes with a out of the box preference for third party libraries, and for DXA to work you should not let Websphere determine which to use, but chose those from DXA (since the different versions are not always compatible with eachother, and the ones from DXA are the only you should need and are tested to work). However if you could specify further, then maybe somebody can respond in more detail.

Comment: The question as written pretty much sums up the problem. If I see jars from tomcat, I can make an educated guess that they aren't used for the core functionality of DXA. What I'm missing is a clear strategy for figuring this out.

Comment: I read that you see jars from tomcat and jboss, but my crystal ball still isn't working after all these years, so could you please **edit** your question and provide details in what you (think) you are seeing? If you would ask why `xyz.jar` is referenced as a dependency, you can possibly get a clear answer.

Comment: Hi Bart. It sounds like your answer is that my strategy should be to list my jars here and wait for help. So far, it's the only answer I've had, so maybe there's some merit in it. :-)

Comment: I can't answer your question on how to determine whether a given dependency is only present to support a given platform, because it is too broad. Dependencies are there for several reasons and for any individual to figure out why they are there exactly, you should start with finding out which classes and methods are used from that certain jar, which hopefully might give you an indication why that dependency is there. But if you would make your question less broad and more clear, you have a chance on an actual answer, that is all I'm saying.